# how to create NSMutableArray dynamically based on certain condition in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a array of dates, so based on certain condition of date I need to create a NSmutablearray and add some values to that particular array. so number of sections in my tableview depends on this mutablearray count(which is internally depends on condition of date).

for example:

```
if(date1)
1.create array1
2.add x,y,z values to the array1.

if(date2)
1.create array2
2.add xx,yy,zz values to the array2.

....
```

thanks..

Comment: I need to create a NSmutablearray dynamically...

Answer (score 11):

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray array];
if (b) {
  [a addObject: ... some object based on "b" being true ...];
  ... etc ...
} else if (c) {
  [a addObject: ... some object based on "c" being true ...];
  ... etc ...
} else {
  [a addObject: ... some object based on neither "c" nor "b" being true ...];
  ... etc ...
}
```

Comment: DON'T USE array: with NSMutableArray. It's not supported and only by cheer luck does it return an mutable array. the only valid way to create an NSMutableArray is arrayWithCapacity: (check  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSMutableArray/arrayWithCapacity: )

Comment: Lol, methinks bbum knows what he's talking about. It's not by sheer luck, it's by design. The primary reason `NSArray` defines the `+array` method is specifically with `NSMutableArray` in mind: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/array. (After all, what sense is an empty, immutable array?)

Comment: Discussion
This method is used by mutable subclasses of NSArray.

Availability
Available in Mac OS X v10.0 and later. I agree with NSGod

Comment: `+array` is an exactly correct way of instantiating an instance of `NSMutableArray`.   `+arrayWithCapacity:` is effectively synonymous with a hint about capacity.

Comment: LordT, you should take anything Bbum has to say about Objective-C, the Cocoa libraries, and Apple's development tools as authoritative.

Comment: It is an easy mistake to make.  The documentation strives to *not repeat information* and, to that ends, the class documentation assumes an understanding of Object Oriented Programming and, specifically, inheritance.   Teach a dev one method, they can write one line of code.  Teach a dev a pattern, and they can write an application!

Answer (score -2):

[Responding to LordT's comment]

"Don't" is a strong word considering that

NSMutableArray *aMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array]; // compiles but invokes +array in NSMutableArray's parent class since +array is not declared in NSMutableArray. What you get if you inspect the object returned by the message expression is an NSArray.

If you really want to use +array but not NSMutableArray class method +arrayWithCapacity: , perhaps

NSMutableArray *aMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray array] mutableCopy];

will suffice? Just don't forget to memory manage.  8)

Comment: Incorrect. Methods don't need to be declared in the header to override them. NSMutableArray overrides +array to do the right thing. NSArray is not introspectable, i.e. you can't tell by examining it whether you got a mutable one or not, only by trying it or knowing what the method returns. This is why +array is declared to return id, not NSArray*.